# My radio buttons won't respond to hover

Tags: javascript, css, html

So what I'm trying to get is when you hover the word span, an image will appear. However, when I hover, nothing happens. I've tried all techniques to do this but no success.

HTML:

```
<div href="javascript:void();" onClick="document.getElementById('avThemes').style.display='block';">
    <input type="radio" name="theme" value="available" id="available" onclick="" /> Available Themes
</div><br />
<div id="avThemes"> 
    <span id="container1"><input type="radio" name="theme" value="greenWaves" id="greenWaves" />
        <a id="gw">Green Waves</a>
    </span>
    <span id="container2"><input type="radio" name="theme" value="purpleLove" id="purpleLove" />Purple Love</span>
</div>
<br />
<img src="images/themes/greenWaves/preview.gif" id="preview1" class="preview" />
<img src="images/themes/purpleLove/preview.gif" id="preview2" class="preview" />
```

CSS:

```
#avThemes {
    display: none;
}

#preview1, #preview2 {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    top: 500px;
    left: 20px;
}

#container1:hover #preview1{
    display: block;
}
```

I also have tried using this which also have failed. Can someone help me figure this out? Thanks!

```
$('#container1').mouseover(function() {
        $('#preview1').fadeIn("slow");
      });
$('#container1').mouseleave(function() {
        $('#preview1').fadeOut("slow");
      });
```

Comment: You have hidden `#avThemes` using `display:none` – so how do you expect to be able to hover over its child element `#container1` when that is not even displayed …?

Comment: In your current implementation, you have hidden the whole avThemes container for some reason, so you can't even hover the two additional inputs. Other than that I tried out your code and it works, it's not very polished in terms of visual appearance but the images loading works.

Comment: In addtion, did you put your js code in the scope of $(document).ready ?

Comment: I'm sorry. I have updated the code. I believe I did not include this earlier. `<div href="javascript:void();" onClick="document.getElementById('avThemes').style.display='block';">`

Comment: So, is it possible if I want to display the image after `#avThemes` is displayed with the onclick?

Comment: No, I did not include it, Peter. *facepalm* Thanks.
Also, if you don't mind, would you suggest a more polished way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try This.....

HTML

```
<input type="radio" name="theme" value="available" id="available" onclick="" /> 
 Available 
 Themes<br />
 <div id="avThemes">
<span id="container1"><input type="radio" name="subtheme" value="greenWaves"
id="greenWaves" /><a id="gw">Green Waves</a></span>
 </div>
<img src="images/themes/greenWaves/preview.gif" id="preview1" class="preview" />
```

css

```
 #avThemes {
 display: none;
  }

#preview1, #preview2 {
display:none;
}
```

javascript

```
  $('#available').click(function() {
  $('#avThemes').show();
  });

 $('#container1').mouseover(function() {
//alert("fdf");
    $('#preview1').fadeIn("slow");
  });
  $('#container1').mouseleave(function() {
    $('#preview1').fadeOut("slow");
  });
```

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/SYw25/1/)

Comment: Thanks, rakhee. I tried this and it worked! Although, I used show and hide instead. =)

Answer (score 0):

May try this -

```
 $(document).on("mouseenter","#container1",function(){

                   //Implementation

                   });
```

Comment: Thanks, Ishank. I'll give this a try. Yes. It will be visible when you click on the input above it.